# Establishing communication between an Android and a non-Android device

Tags: android, sockets, communication

I wish to establish communication between two devices, one Android and the other non-Android. The other device functions by searching for a socket client, and the device itself functions as a socket server. It does obtain an IP Address, and a port number, and now in my application, I wish for the program to search for the empty sockets, and it seems, that the normal socket programming won't be good enough for this. I might need to include the mDNS or NSD kind of thing into it.

Anyone with a hint, how to accomplish the task ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing an Android server is not that different from the standard Java implementation.

```
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
 while (true) {
      Socket newClient = serverSocket.accept(); // block until new connection
      <IO with newClient>
 }
```

As for the IO part: you could do standard blocking IO, which will probably
 require you to spawn additional threads, or you could use [Android nio API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html)

Now:

The [serverSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) code must run on a dedicated thread

if you plan a long running server you will probably want to place it in a
 dedicated service. Threads spawned directly by an activity may be swapped by Android
after their activity moves to background.

Services are much better in that respect. But services also go down finally.

So, if the server is really important for your system you will need a way
 to tell Android not to kill it when resources go low. The way to do it is by declaring your service
 as a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground):

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Foreground services are more stable than standard services, but they do not prevent Android from going to
sleep, and nothing works when you sleep..  If you *really* need your app to prevent the device from sleeping, 
you will need to acquire a [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). Wake locks are very expensive in terms of battery consumption. Handle with care.

As for the client code (I assume Java client) - it can look like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerActivity.SERVERPORT);
while (true) {
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
   <write to peer>
   socket.close();
}
```

One last tricky bit: you'll have to figure out a way of pass server's IP address 
to its peer. Remember - this is mobile and the network you are using 
can change periodically. To fetch the server IP addr use:

```
String getDeviceIpAddr() {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface network = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> addr = network.getInetAddresses(); addr.hasMoreElements();) {
             InetAddress inetAddress = addr.nextElement();
             if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                 return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

And you will need some way of passing it to the server's clients. many use a relay server for that.

Comment: I implemented a thread, an Async Task class, for the working of the socket. Since I am trying to communicate over wifi, I search for an open socket over wifi, but of no use. It's not working!

Comment: `07-02 15:41:20.217: W/System.err(2614): java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`